# Manipulating the list with variables

Tags: list-manipulation, algebraic-manipulation, assignment

I am trying to find the maximum element of the list for a given value of variable $c$.
The example of the list is as follows:

```
List = {-1 + 6 (1 - c/2), -(9/10) + 6 (1 - c/2)}
```

I am trying to implement the following command:

```
Manipulate[Max[List], {c, 0, 2}]
```

Of course, it does not work. I guess Mathematica has some straightforward way of implementing this unknown to me. Any hint would be appreciated

Comment: (1) `List` is a built-in symbol. You can't set it's value. It is recommended that you use variable names that begin with lowercase (no built-in symbols are lowercase, so you know there won't be a name collision), or else use a naming pattern that you know won't result in name collisions.

Comment: @lericr noted, thank you. Luckily, I am using a different name in the actual file.

Comment: (2) Manipulate will set up a sort of local scope for variable names. You used `c` as the dynamic variable in the Manipulate, but the "real" name of that variable will be different. So, the `c` in your list (defined outside of the Manipulate) is not the same `c` in the `list` expression.

Comment: You can either pull the expression explicitly into the Manipulate (rather than indirectly via a variable like `list`, or you can turn the static `list` variable into a function. Then pass your Manipulate `c` to the function inside the Manipulate.

Comment: My "or" wasn't intended to imply that these were the only two options. :)

Comment: @lericr Thank you!

Comment: Note that the first element of this list is never greater than the second element. `Reduce[Greater @@ list]` evaluates to `False`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to be explicit, here is a fairly clean way:

```
myExpression[arg_] := {-1 + 6 (1 - arg/2), -(9/10) + 6 (1 - arg/2)}

Manipulate[Max[myExpression[c]], {c, 0, 2}]
```